# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString

Tags: asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

I recently created an application in Visual Studio 2015 following the link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-dotnet-application/

But when I build the solution, it showed me the following error:

> Value cannot be `null`.
>   Parameter name: `uriString`
>   Line 71: `public static void Initialize()`
>   Line 72: `{`
>   Line 73: `client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["https://<db-name>.documents.azure.com:443/"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<db-key>"]);`
>   Line 74: `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();`
>   Line 75: `CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();`
>
> Source File: `C:\Users\BHAVIN PATEL\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\documentdb-dotnet-todo-app-master\src\DocumentDBRepository.cs`    Line: 73

I have inserted the URI and Primary/Secondary Key in `Web.config` file of my application from the DocumentDB application created in Azure.

Comment: Is there any `appSetting` with the key "https://bhavin-patel.documents.azure.com:443/" in your App.config?

Comment: Before **ANYTHING** else: Please change your database account access key immediately - you just published it to the world. I edited it out for you, but people can still get to it.

Comment: Please don't remove the question and replace with the solution. The question should stay as just that, a question whilst the answer section can be used to advise other people what you did to fix the problem. Or if the current answer fixes the problem, consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: As Bugs said: answers do not belong in the question. If you want to answer your own question, then you may do so. But please leave the question alone.

Comment: Just in case it helps, the `uriString` it's talking about is from this ctor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-uri-ctor(system-string)

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error when I was running my `Azure Function`.

[image]

I was reading one of the connection string value from `Azure Key Vault` and I had set this in the app settings of my Azure Function configuration. As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/), it is mandatory to set the `Managed Identity` for the Azure Function and created an `Access Policy` in the Key Vault configuration by using the managed identity object created, so that Azure Function application can read the values from the Key Vault.

I was missing this settings, so that the app setting value of the key `ServiceBusConnectionString` was always null, thus the mentioned error. After configuring the access policy, the error was gone. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the database endpoint and key should be in the .config file, like this

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="documentDbEndpoint" value="https://bhavin-patel.documents.azure.com:443/"/>
  <add key="documentDbKey" value="naw1rq0lhaPwzCSI1w69EQYEfUeL0rU*********************************"/>
</appSettings>
```

And you should then use the configuration manager to read the setting by the key

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentDbEndpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentDbKey"]);
```

Remember to use the correct documentDbKey from the portal. I have masked part of your key with *